# In Debian based systems, how do we purge configuration files of packages that have already been uninstalled?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, package-management, apt, packaging

To be more specific, I would like to do the equivalent of adding the `--purge` flag to the following command

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge [package name]
```

to packages that are no longer on the system.

Preferably, I would like to know how to do it to specific packages and to every uninstalled package in the system.

Comment: The question is not clearly worded. I assume you mean - "how does one remove configuration files from packages that have been removed from the system, but still have configuration files installed". Bringing in `autoremove` is just confusing, imo.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Changed the title according to your suggestions. But I think the autoremove only would make things confusing if I didn't write anything else. But the sentence "I would like to do the equivalent of adding the --purge flag to the following command" makes things clear.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The following should do what you want:

```
aptitude purge \~c
```

This purges all packages with the `c` (package removed, configuration files still present) state flag. Flag documentation is [here](http://algebraicthunk.net/~dburrows/projects/aptitude/doc/en/ch02s02s02.html#figureCurrentFlag).

Comment: Sorry, it's not working

line 1> # sudo aptitude purge '-c'  
line 2> aptitude: invalid option -- 'c'

Comment: @AlexandreMartins The first character in the quotes is a tilde, not a hyphen.

Comment: `aptitude purge ~c` works as well

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni Not reliably. `~[user]` is a valid POSIX tilde expansion.

Comment: @Chris Down Ok, in the case you have a user named `c`

Answer (score 8):

For those who don't want to install `aptitude`:

```
sudo dpkg -P $(dpkg -l | awk '/^rc/ { print($2) }')
```

Answer (score 2):

The `--purge` flag removes configuration files for packages that are no longer installed. I don't recommend blindly removing configuration files for all uninstalled packages. You might want to keep some of them. For an individual package, `dpkg -P` will work (`-P` stands for `--purge`). Here `alacarte` only has its configuration files installed, hence the `rc` flags. E.g.

```
orwell:/home/faheem# dpkg -l alacarte
[...]
rc  alacarte                           0.11.5-1                           easy GNOME menu editing tool
orwell:/home/faheem# dpkg -P alacarte
(Reading database ... 345418 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing alacarte ...
Purging configuration files for alacarte ...
orwell:/home/faheem# dpkg -l alacarte
[...]
un  alacarte                           <none>                             (no description available)
```

Comment: Usually, I keep the important configurations in my own home folder. This means the --purge flag does not do anything problematic to me. And it actually helps me not having any problems later on. Is there any good reason you say I shouldn't use --purge that I'm missing?

Comment: @AlexandreMartins: If you are sure you don't have any configuration in any of the system config files, that is fine, I guess. That is definitely not the case for me though.

Answer (score -1):

```
aptitude --clean-on-startup
```

That should clear the package cache.

Comment: Following the manuale page: "Cleans the package cache when the program starts". This is not what the OP asked.